# Retrive inbound message data in mobile connect marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, mobileconnect

someone knows if the only ways to capture an incoming sms (phone, message, keyword) in SFMC is with ampscript by "Text Response Type" or with "Info Capture"?

additionally, whenever you send the "text response" sms with ampscript to capture the response data, will it count as a regular sms even if you don't send an actual response (choose to not include a response)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes those are the out of the box solutions where you can handle the response via AMPScript. You can also look at the responses using the new data view [SMS Message Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5). It will log the entire message itself if you're just looking for the response and don't wish to code any logic around the response. There is also the SMS Send Log that can be enabled to provide a similar solution of capturing the responses.

As a note on the second question. It is always best practice to respond to the contact in SMS because the communication is back and forth and is better user experience to let them know that their response was captured.